# Method or object constructor not found in f#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, xna

I have been trying to learn f# over the past few weeks and am having a little trouble with certain aspects. I am trying to use it with XNA and am writing a very simple game.

I have a simple player class that implements DrawableGameComponent and then overrides its methods Draw, Update and LoadContent.

```
type Player (game:Game) =
        inherit DrawableGameComponent(game)

        let game = game
        let mutable position = new Vector2( float32(0), float32(0) )
        let mutable direction = 1
        let mutable speed = -0.1
        let mutable sprite:Texture2D = null

        override this.LoadContent() =
             sprite <- game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprite")

        override this.Update gt= 
            if direction = -1 && this.Coliding then
                this.Bounce
            this.Jumping
            base.Update(gt)

        override this.Draw gt=
            let spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(game.GraphicsDevice)
            spriteBatch.Begin()
            spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, position, Color.White)
            spriteBatch.End()
            base.Draw(gt)
```

and so on....

The main Game class then makes a new player object etc.

```
module Game=

    type XnaGame() as this =
        inherit Game()

        do this.Content.RootDirectory <- "XnaGameContent"
        let graphicsDeviceManager = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this)

        let mutable player:Player = new Player(this)
        let mutable spriteBatch : SpriteBatch = null
        let mutable x = 0.f
        let mutable y = 0.f
        let mutable dx = 4.f
        let mutable dy = 4.f

        override game.Initialize() =
            graphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsProfile <- GraphicsProfile.HiDef
            graphicsDeviceManager.PreferredBackBufferWidth <- 640
            graphicsDeviceManager.PreferredBackBufferHeight <- 480
            graphicsDeviceManager.ApplyChanges() 
            spriteBatch <- new SpriteBatch(game.GraphicsDevice)
            base.Initialize()

        override game.LoadContent() =
            player.LoadContent () //PROBLEM IS HERE!!!
            this.Components.Add(player)

        override game.Update gameTime = 
            player.Update gameTime


        override game.Draw gameTime = 
            game.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue)
            player.Draw gameTime
```

The compiler reports an error saying "Method or object constructor LoadContent not found"

I find this odd as both Draw and Update work ok and are found by intellisense but not LoadContent!

It is probably just a very silly error I have made but if anyone spots the problem I would be much obliged!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DrawableGameComponent.LoadContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.drawablegamecomponent.loadcontent.aspx) is protected - so you don't have access to call it from your `XnaGame` class.

It's not clear to me what's meant to end up calling it, but apparently you shouldn't be calling it directly yourself.

Comment: Thanks! This makes total sense, thanks for pointing this out! So if i just add my object to the games Components then it should be called automatically?  Thanks again!

Comment: @EwenCluley: I don't know, to be honest - I suspect so, but I haven't done any XNA work myself.

Answer (score 2):

The error definitely sounds confusing. You're overriding the `LoadContent` member in the definition of your `Player` type, but (as Jon pointed out) the member is `protected`. F# does not allow you to make the member more visible, so even your definition is still `protected` (you cannot normally define `protected` members in F#, so that's why the error message is poor).

You can solve the problem by adding additional member that calls `LoadContent` from inside the `Player`:

```
override this.LoadContent() = 
    sprite <- game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprite") 
member this.LoadContentPublic() = 
    this.LoadContent()
```

...then the `LoadContent` member will still be `protected` (inaccessible from the outside), but the new `LoadContentPublic` member will be public (this is default for `member` in F#) and you should be able to call it from your `XnaGame`.

However, as Jon pointed out - maybe you shouldn't be calling the method yourself because the XNA runtime will call it automatically when it needs to.

Comment: Great, very useful and indepth answer. thansk for this it makes sense- I seam to recal that in c# i could change the visibility of an overridden method... i think... odd that f# doesnt allow this. Thansk for the help!